# Merging leaves in a forest tree

Tags: forest

I am trying to get the leaves a a tree to converge, like this:

[image]

But I don't want `B_{n-2}(x)` to be drawn twice, I want `B_{n-2}(x)` to be at the terminus of two lines, one originating from `B_{n-1}(x+1/2)`, and the other originating from `B_{n-1}(x-1/2)`.

Is this possible?

Here's my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$B_n(x)$
    [$B_{n-1}(x+1/2)$
        [$B_{n-2}(x+1)$]
        [$B_{n-2}(x)$]
    ]
    [$B_{n-1}(x-1/2)$
        [$B_{n-2}(x)$]
        [$B_{n-2}(x-1)$]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multidominant structures are not trees any more, and so the standard tree packages don't have a good way to deal with them. The general technique is to make a node with no edge and then draw the edges to the shared node manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}for tree={math content}
[B_n(x)
    [B_{n-1}(x+1/2),name=S1
        [B_{n-2}(x+1)]
        [B_{n-2}(x),phantom]
    ]
    [B_{n-2}(x),tier=term,no edge,name=shared]
    [B_{n-1}(x-1/2),name=S2
        [B_{n-2}(x),phantom]
        [B_{n-2}(x-1),tier=term]
    ]
]
\draw (S2) -- (shared);
\draw (S1) -- (shared);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Do you think another package would be more appropriate for this task since this is not a tree? The solution is great nonetheless.

Comment: If you're drawing a lot of these, then the graph drawing library of TikZ might be more appropriate. See e.g. [Tree like but with more arrows](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/415473) also [Multi-rooted Tree-like Structures and Nodes with Multiple Parents in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/114109).